# Андроид Студио. Как программно изменить размер шрифта (увеличить / уменьшить шрифты) во всём приложении? (не в одном элементе!)

Tags: android, android-studio

**Не в одном** элементе, а **во всех** элементах **всех** форм **всего** приложения.

Например, увеличить на 20%, в полтора, 2 раза... И т.д.

Пока обхожусь разными стилями под разные устройства.

Но, иногда, народ сам хочет настраивать размер шрифта для приложения. )

Comment: совершенно не ясен вопрос, что вы хотите? Если хотите программно увеличить шрифт на 20%  --> textSize * 0.2  Хотите в 2 раза --> textSize * 2.0 Зачем стиль для этого нужен?

Answer (score 2):

Есть [вариант использовать стили](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24571488/5330439), но по-моему такая гибкость предполагает только несколько размеров.  Размеры должны быть заготовлены заранее.

Можно так.

```
private void multTextSize(float mult) {
    float sizeDefault = 10;
    float sizeMult = sizeDefault * mult;
    textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeMult);
    textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeMult);
    editText1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeMult);
    editText2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeMult);
}
```

Создайте метод, соберите там все view, которым требуется изменить размер текста передавайте туда параметром множитель.

*Наверняка есть более изящное решение, буду следить за вашим вопросом*

Comment: Спасибо буду думать. )